# How to "push" c++ map like it's done in javascript

Tags: c++

In C++ I'd like to "push" key/value objects into an array, exactly like I do in JavaScript.

Here is what I would normally do in JavaScript:

```
var people = [];
var males = [];

people.push({ name: 'david',age: 45,sex: 'male'});
people.push({ name: 'mary',age: 22,sex: 'female'});
people.push({ name: 'alan',age: 52,sex: 'male'});
people.push({ name: 'fred',age: 19,sex: 'male'});
people.push({ name: 'alice',age: 33,sex: 'female'});

for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++)
{
    if (people[i].sex == 'male')
    {
        males.push({
            name: people[i].name,
            age: people[i].age,
            sex: people[i].sex
        });
    }
}
```

This is my attempt at it in C++:

```
int foo()
{
    std::map<std::string, int> aData;

    MySQL my;
    char szQueryText[200] = { '\0' };
    MYSQL_RES *My_result = nullptr;

    snprintf(szQueryText, sizeof(szQueryText), "SELECT * FROM %s.object_affixes WHERE objType = %d ORDER BY rowID ASC;", DB_DATA, 1);
    My_result = MySQL__query(szQueryText);
    int num = my.Query(szQueryText);

    while (num > 0)
    {
        my.NextRow();
        num--;

        aData.insert('rangeFrom', atoi(my.GetData("rangeFrom")));
    }
    MySQL__endquery(My_result);
```

In my C++ example, I'd like to iterate through the while() loop just like I did in the for() loop js example, which I'm doing fine.  In C++ I need to build a new *array* (just like my males[] js array) and *push* the iterated data into it.

How do I get C++ std::map to do this correctly?  Do I even use std::map or should I be using something else?

Comment: Please post code as text and not images.

Comment: the javascript code you are showing is not a 'map' like structure. So it does not make sense to ask how to do it with a map in c++. All you have is an array of objects. @ThomasMatthews answers address that

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
struct Person
{
  std::string name;
  size_t      age;
  std::string sex;
};

std::vector<Person> database;
Person p("Fred", 21, "male");
database.push_back(p);
```

The C++ language is not JavaScript, so you'll have to do things the C++ way.

You could try something like this:

```
database.push_back(Person("Alice", 19, "female"));
```

Comment: @pm100 A map is the wrong way to solve the problem in C++. Assuming that name, age and sex are the same for each entry, a struct is the right thing to use.

Answer (score 0):

Which [container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) to use, depends on what it will be used for.

For a vector, you could [emplace_back](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back)(available since C++11):

```
struct Person
{
  std::string name;
  size_t      age;
  std::string sex;
};

std::vector<Person> database;
//... 
database.emplace_back("david", 45, "male");
```